# Google calendar sync with Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

I have migrated my emails and calendar to Google Apps, but I don't get the categories in my calendar back on Outlook if I sync from Google.

Comment: how do you sync Google Apps and Outlook ? Which version of Outlook do you use ?

Comment: Outlook 2003, I have migrated to Goolge Apps using the Google Apps Migration. After migration I used Google Sync Tool to create new profile in Outlook and synced with google, However My calendar Catogeries are missing in Outlook !

Comment: maybe you could try other solutions than Google Sync Tool. admintech provided a few in his answer

Answer (score 2):

I found that [gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit4/) is the most feature-rich software that does what you asked here, and more. It worked much better for me than other available solutions. I use this software to sync my contacts and calendars from my and my wife's Outlook to our Android phones, and it works! E.g. it can automacially sync to a different Google calendar based on Outlook category.

Answer (score -1):

I tried Google Sync but had too many issues with it. Found [SyncMyCal](http://www.syncmycal.com/) through a web search and have been pretty happy with it. It’s not the prettiest interface but since it can be set to automatic, you never really look at it. One of the best features is the ability to be able to set up multiple sync “operations” to take categories or groups of categories in Outlook and put them in different Google calendars.

It also does contact syncing but I’ve a little less success with that. Also, the latest version is quite old — not sure if they’re keeping it up to date. And it’s not free.

Another option is [Oggsync](http://oggsync.com) but i havent used that