# How can I set up a Google calendar to subscribe to my Exchange/Outlook calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google calendar sync with Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/300664/google-calendar-sync-with-outlook)

**Note:** Google Calendar Sync is no longer supported as of December 14, 2012.  I'm checking if there is any other available solution.

I want to expose the appointment calendar in my employer's Exchange/Outlook service, to my Google Calendar account.  I want to have a calendar in the My Calendars list, which is a view of my Exchange/Outlook calendar.

It does not need to be 2-way sync.  I just want to be able to view the appointments in my Exchange calendar while in Google calendar.

Comment: Whenever I'm looking for alterntaives to software I try to check out: http://alternativeto.net/ Here they make a few recomendations. http://alternativeto.net/software/google-calendar-sync/

Comment: Until Microsoft updates Outlook to support the standard that is supported by Google Calendar if you don't have a copy of Google Sync already you are out of luck.

Comment: I'm sure you can find a version of google calendar somewhere...

Comment: Really don't see how this is getting "exact duplicate" votes; the question content is clearly very different!

Comment: I am evaluating the software solutions suggested in response to the [Google calendar sync with Outlook](http://superuser.com/questions/300664/google-calendar-sync-with-outlook) question.  I will follow up here if one of them meets my needs.

Comment: The free evaluation distro of [gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/index.shtml) does exactly what I need.